Можно ли сохранить такую совокупность классов в БД C#+EF?
В общем, есть вот такая структура:

Используя такую структуру EF не позволяет мне создать базу данных, так как в сущности ExpertSystem три свойства одного и того же типа, на примерном коде будет понятнее:
Сущности:
public class ExpertSystem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Operation> InitialOperations { get; set; }

    public List<Operation> CompletionOperations { get; set; }

    public List<Operation> VariablesOperations { get; set; }
}
public class Input : Operation
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Variable Variable { get; set; }

    public int VariableId { get; set; }
}
public class Output : Operation
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Variable? Variable { get; set; }
    public int? VariableId { get; set; }
}
public class Operation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ExpertSystem ExpertSystem { get; set; }

    public int ExpertSystemId { get; set; }
}
public class Variable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

При попытке создать БД вылетел Exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: "Unable to determine the
relationship represented by navigation 'Expert
System.CompletionOperations' of type 'List'. Either
manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
'[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
'OnModelCreating'."
Попробовал настроить через метод OnModelCrating():

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ExpertSystem> ExpertSystems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Output> Outputs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Input> Inputs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Variable> Variables { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertSystem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.InitialOperations)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ExpertSystemId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertSystem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.CompletionOperations)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ExpertSystemId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertSystem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.VariablesOperations)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ExpertSystemId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

Все равно та же ошибка. Можно как нибудь это исправить? Мне необходимо в сущности экспертной системы разделить связи с операциями на блоки.

Я не вижу никаких проблем. Должно работать.

@AlexanderPetrov я подумал что проблема может быть в том, что я использую родительский класс и не знаю, как он будет представлен в БД. И что связь с ним идет у меня, и как это все в БД интерпретируется.

С наследованием EF хорошо умеет работать. Inheritance. Тут скорее некоторые проблемы могут быть с тремя навигационными свойствами, каждое из которых имеет одинаковый тип List<Operation>.

@AlexanderPetrov да кстати, и это тоже. Сможет ли он так связать, и смогу ли я потом доставать именно нужные мне операции.

Меньше слов, больше кода! Начинайте писать код сущностей и контекста и выкладывайте сюда. Чем эти свойства отличаются? Почему нужны три списка?

Ну что там, есть подвижки?

@AlexanderPetrov я изменил вопрос, добавил пример. Извините что долго не заходил, был другим занят.
